# Using an array for unique copy from multiple sheets / VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have been working on a macro that summarizes the data from multiple sheets in my workbook. In order to know which columns to use in my summary sheet I need to first extract all the unique values from the first column in my sheets.

The idea is that it will loop through the sheets and define a range, then it will loop through each cell in the range, check if the value of that cell is already in the array and if not copy and paste it and add it to the array.

Unfortunately I get an the error "Index outside of valid Area" for the line that is supposed to add the cell value to the array.

```
ReDim Preserve uniqueVal(1 To UBound(uniqueVal) + 1) As Variant
```

I took that specific code from the question https://superuser.com/questions/808798/excel-vba-adding-an-element-to-the-end-of-an-array .

Here is the entire code for reference.

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()

    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim copyRng As Range
    Dim destRng As Range
    Dim cRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim uniqueVal() As Variant

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the summary worksheet if it exists.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Add a worksheet with the name "Summary"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "Summary"
    Set destRng = DestSh.Range("A1")

    'Define inital array values
    uniqueVal = Array("Account by Type", "Total")

    ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' summary worksheet.
    For Each xSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If InStr(1, xSheet.Name, "ACCOUNT") And xSheet.Range("B1") <> "No Summary Available" Then _

            Set copyRng = xSheet.Range("A:A")

            For Each c In copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                If Len(c) <> 0 And Not ISIN(c, uniqueVal) Then _

                    'Copy to destination Range
                    c.Copy destRng
                    'move destination Range
                    Set destRng = destRng.Offset(0, 1)
                    'change / adjust the size of array
                    ReDim Preserve uniqueVal(1 To UBound(uniqueVal) + 1) As Variant
                    'add value on the end of the array
                    uniqueVal(UBound(uniqueVal)) = c.Value

                End If

            Next c

        End If

    Next xSheet

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of the `ReDim Preserve uniqueVal(1 To UBound(uniqueVal) + 1) As Variant`. Can you use `ReDim Preserve uniqueVal(1 To UBound(uniqueVal) - 1) As Variant`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help. I changed the + to a - and I still get the same error message.

Comment: Why is there an underscore at the end of this line `If Len(c) <> 0 And Not ISIN(c, uniqueVal) Then _` ?

Comment: @Variatus I am not sure, I just saw it written like that and started using it. I have learned that if I don't put the underscore there the If statement sometimes doesn't work the way I would expect it to or sometimes even ignores an End If at the end of it. I doubt however, that the issue lies in the underscore since I have run this code without the problematic line and gives me the result I want, expect of course that it contains duplicates. I have been considering the option where I simply write some extra code to remove this after the loop has finished.

Comment: @FSchildorfer the underscore at `If Len(c) <> 0 And Not ISIN(c, uniqueVal) Then _` is clearly a typo - it tells VBA that there is no linebreak, therefore it interprets the next line of code as part of the current line.
Since the next line is empty, it's not harmful in this case... still dirty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per default, arrays in Excel VBA start with the index `0`, not the index `1`. You can test this by checking your arrays contents: your first string `"Account by Type"` should be on `uniqueval(0)` rather than on `uniqueval(1)`.

Two ways to solve this:

1. add `Option Base 1` to the top of your module **or**
2. change `ReDim Preserve uniqueval(1 To UBound(uniqueval) + 1)` to `ReDim Preserve uniqueval(0 To UBound(uniqueval) + 1)`

It's up to you which one you chose, but imo the latter is cleaner, since you don't have to fiddle with array options on module level.

As I see it, you're not actually using the arrays' contents yet. If you do later on, just loop `For i = LBound(uniqueval) To UBound(uniqueval)` - in which case it is irrelevant with what option you went.

Comment: You can use the line of code `For i = LBound(uniqueval) To UBound(uniqueval)` as suggested by @Martin

Comment: @Martin Dreher this seem to have done the trick. Thank you very much!Unfortunately my excel doc always almost crashes while running this sub. I wonder what it is that is such a burden on this specific sub when the others ones I wrote seem to be a lot longer and complex.

Comment: **almost** everytime? Is there an error message? Not tested, but I recon that since `For Each c In copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` does a shitload of loops (likely, 1.048.576 times if there are no filters) that might be too much. I would also not be surprised if applied filters would actually mess things up. There is a max. size to VBA-arrays, but I doubt you got that many ISINs
Maybe exit the loop prematurely.

Comment: ah, changing `c.copy destrng` to `destrng.value = c.value` could also help

Answer (score 0):

On the first loop uniqueVal has no Ubound. That's why it fails. So, you should first Redim it as Redim uniqueVal(1 To 1), then write to the Ubound and increase the size thereafter. That would always leave you with a blank element at the top which you can remove at the end.
The better (because it runs faster) is to Dim uniqueVal to a possible max number, then set the current index with a counter, like i = i + 1, and do a Redim Preserve uniqueVal(i) at the end, thereby cutting off all unused elements.

The underscore at the end of a line of code means that the line is continued, logically, in the next line. For example,

```
If 1 <> 2 Then _
    Debug.Print "All is well"
```

This is the same as `If 1 <> 2 Then Debug.Print "All is well"`
Observe, however, that there is no `End If`. If there were more than one command to follow the `Then` you must use `End If`, for example,

```
If 1 <> 2 Then
    Debug.Print "All is well"
    A = 3
End If
```

Here, everything between `If` and `End If` will only be executed if `1 <> 2`. This is the case with `If Len(c) <> 0 And Not ISIN(c, uniqueVal) Then _`. Once the error of the UBound is cured this one will stop your code from running. Remove the underscore following the `Then`.

Comment: seems way too messy, since he cant write the initial values with `uniqueval = Array("Account by Type", "Total")` then. Imagine if there are ten instead of two values... I recon you wouldn't want to add a line of code for each.

Comment: @MartinDreher is right. In the final code there are actually 17 values (all names of different stock exchanges) which I left out in this first attempt, since I just wanted to get it to work first.

Comment: in this particular case, the underscore wont stop the code, since there is an empty line of code beneath it ;) you are, however, right that the underscore should be omitted