# Copy all Worksheets using an Array

Tags: excel, vba

I've researched my query online and could not find an exact matching resolution.  This is probably very simple but I have not found a closely related answer that could help me resolve this specifically.

How can I use the arrays function to copy all worksheets in a workbook?  I'm trying to use the open-sourced code snippet below:

```
'Copy the sheets to a new workbook
    'We add a temporary Window to avoid the Copy problem
    'if there is a List or Table in one of the sheets and
    'if the sheets are grouped
    With Sourcewb
        Set TheActiveWindow = ActiveWindow
        Set TempWindow = .NewWindow
        .Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3")).Copy
    End With
```

Specific worksheet names are being mentioned here ("Sheet1", "Sheet3").  I'm trying to copy all of worksheets in the active workbook, not specific workbooks.  Can a reference to all worksheets like one object representing all worksheets be inserted into the arguments list, or do arrays only work with references to multiple worksheets?
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I hope this post will have an answer for your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812894/using-an-array-for-unique-copy-from-multiple-sheets-vba

Comment: I did see that earlier Gilson.  It didn't help my particular use case.  Thanks for your reference though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all the sheet name in the array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Wb As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet
    Dim toWb As Workbook
    Dim vName()
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set toWb = Workbooks(2)
    
    For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vName(1 To n)
        vName(n) = Ws.Name
    Next Ws
    Wb.Sheets(vName).Copy After:=toWb.Sheets(toWb.Sheets.Count)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### (Work)Sheet Names to Array

Instead of `.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3")).Copy`, using the functions under '*The Code*', you can use one of the following:

- when you want to copy only worksheets:

  ```
  .Sheets(getWorksheetNames(Sourcewb)).Copy
  ```
- when you want to include other sheet types like charts, macro sheets or dialogs:

  ```
  .Sheets(getSheetNames(Sourcewb)).Copy
  ```

if you made sure that `Sourcewb` 'is not nothing' and for `getWorksheetNames`, that there is at least one worksheet in the workbook.

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes all worksheet names to a 1D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getWorksheetNames(Book As Workbook) _
         As Variant
    
    If Book Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    If Book.Worksheets.Count = 0 Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If

    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To Book.Worksheets.Count)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each ws In Book.Worksheets
        n = n + 1
        Data(n) = ws.Name
    Next ws
    
    getWorksheetNames = Data

ProcExit:
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes all sheet names to a 1D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getSheetNames(Book As Workbook) _
         As Variant
    
    If Book Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To Book.Sheets.Count)
    
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each sh In Book.Sheets
        n = n + 1
        Data(n) = sh.Name
    Next sh
    
    getSheetNames = Data

ProcExit:
End Function

Sub testGetNames()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim ResultString As String
    
    Data = getWorksheetNames(wb)
    ResultString = Join(Data, vbLf)
    Debug.Print "Worksheet Names List" & vbLf & ResultString
    
    Data = getSheetNames(wb)
    ResultString = Join(Data, vbLf)
    Debug.Print "Sheet Names List" & vbLf & ResultString

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a 'ByRef argument type mismatch' on (sourceweb) where .Sheets(getWorksheetNames(SourceWeb)).Copy exists.

Comment: Now you have written `SourceWeb`, but previously you used `Sourcewb`. If this is just a typo or not related to the error, you will have to explain where the error occurs (in which line of the code).

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  'SourceWeb' was a typo.  It's 'Sourcewb.'  I'm getting a 'Variable not defined' error on 'ReDim Preserve vName(1 To n).  I will resubmit the entire code as a new question if I can't figure this out. Thanks for your help

Comment: @brohjoe: You're commenting on the wrong post, I don't have this line in my solution.

Comment: I fixed the 'variable not defined' error, now I'm getting an 'Object variable or With variable not set' error on .Sheets(Array(vName)).Copy After:=Destwb.Sheets(Destwb.Sheets.Count)

Comment: Oh I see, that was Dy.Lee...my bad